# OSGI transitive dependencies level

Tags: java, apache, maven, osgi, bundle

I am currently trying to bundle a nonOSGI maven project. Right now, I have something like,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<!-- The Basics -->
<artifactId>Project1</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>internal.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>internalcommons</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> 
<parent>
    <groupId>internal</groupId>
    <artifactId>jar-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<name>Project 1</name>

<build> 
    <directory>${basedir}/bundles</directory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
                    <Bundle-Version>1.0</Bundle-Version>
                    <Import-Package>*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>
                    <Embed-Dependency>*</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>       
    </plugins>  
</build>
```

My nonOSGI bundle however depends on various different jars, some of these jars have dependencies too. When I bundle the nonOSGI maven project, I can only get the immediate dependencies of this bundle, when I use bundleall, I get an error relating to xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.6.2. I COULD create a bundles of all the dependencies if there is no other option but there are just too many dependencies.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What error related to xml-apis do you have? Could you show your pom?

Comment: Added pom, if I run the current pom I have pasted with just bundle:bundle, I get runtime error Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.OutputFormat not found. Bundle:bundleall results in Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:bundleall (default-cli) on project Project1: Artifact was not found in the repoxml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.6.2:compile: Could not find artifact xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.6.2 in nexus

Comment: If it's possible, please, update your pom with dependencies to let us experiment with it.

Comment: Updated pom, another note that the internal.commons has various dependencies itself and I think thats where the issue is coming in. I am doing runtime reflection in order to work with the bundle and sometimes the dependencies aren't present.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

According to the posted stacktrace there is no `xml-apis:xml-apis:2.6.2` artifact in the [central repo](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3a%22xml-apis%22). I suppose it should be [xerces:xmlParserAPIs:2.6.2](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3a%22xmlParserAPIs%22%20AND%20v%3a%222.6.2%22).
Here is updated pom that does not have problems with embedding deps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- The Basics -->
    <groupId>internal</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <name>Project 1</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 

    <build> 
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.7</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
                        <Bundle-Version>1.0</Bundle-Version>
                        <Import-Package>*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>
                        <Embed-Dependency>*</Embed-Dependency>
                        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>       
        </plugins>  
    </build>

</project>
```

Notice using `packaging=bundle`. To build just execute `mvn package`.

Although maven-bundle-plugin helps with embedding dependencies I highly recommend you not to do it if it's possible to achieve higher modularity of your project. There are repos with prebuilt osgi bundles, for example: [apache servicemix bundles](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/servicemix/bundles/), [spring enterprise bundle repository](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle), etc.

Comment: Using <Import-Package>*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package> is a bad pratice that will mostly end up in a class not found exception at runtime long after the application started running! Also, by blindingly embedding everything you will increase the amount of packages in the Import-Package path which cannot be solved at the compile time. So using <Embed-Dependency>*</Embed-Dependency>
                        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive> is also a bad idea... Unfortunately, there is no solution to this besides doing all the dirty work by hand.

Comment: why you just didn't try to answer the original question, i.e. osgify all your hundereds deps? this is definitely better solution, espesially if you have enough time and money and other deps are osgi-friendly (no different thread-context classloading issues, always loading classes by explicitly provided classloader, no spi usage, etc., etc., etc)